# How do I attach Scroll View's delegate method?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have collection view which contains a scroll view. Scroll view has custom class which has scrollViewDidScroll function.
Whenever I scroll, the scrollViewDidScroll method doesn't trigger.

I tried attaching it's delegate to it's own class, and all the other classes and view controller itself.
I attached each scroll view using cellForItemAt function because each controller has it's own cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom class of `UICollectionView` and then make an outlet of `scrollview` in that class and connect its delegate to it in `awakeFromNib:` method.

Comment: wc. happy coding !!